# String starts with < does not echo in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a string variable like `$content = '<?php ';` and `echo $content;`it's print empty .

What is the issue;

Comment: please learn HTML before PHP

Comment: Check the source of your page in your browser.

Answer (score 2):

You are viewing the output of the PHP script in a web browser.

The browser is trying to render it as HTML.

The `<?php` sequence is treated at the start of an unrecognised start tag or processing instruction.

Either:

Use the View Source feature of your browser to see the outputted code.

**or**

Use [the `htmlspecialchars` function](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to express it in HTML.

```
echo htmlspecialchars($content);
```

**or**

Tell the browser it is plain text and not HTML

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```

(This needs to go before any output from your program).